# Having 2 functions of the same variable, how can I find the derivative of the first function in relation to the other?

Tags: derivatives

Let's be specific and use a simpler example than what I actually need to solve.
$$
\begin{split}
x(t) &= t + A\sin(wt) \\
y(t) &= B \cos(wt)
\end{split}
$$
How would I obtain the derivative of x in y? My maths are pretty rusty :(

I'd like to be able to derive Gerstner wave normal equations by myself, and that would help. Any good book I could find the answer in (the theory) would also be welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}.\frac{dt}{dx}$$

If you want to find: $\frac{dx}{dy}$, Then use

$$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{dx}{dt}.\frac{dt}{dy}$$

Comment: God, I need to retake some basic math classes. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$t=\frac1w\arccos\frac yB$$

Also,
$$\sin(wt)=\sqrt{1-\frac{y^2}{B^2}}$$
for $t\in[0,\frac{\pi}w]$.

Therefore,
$$x=\frac1w\arccos\frac yB+A\sqrt{1-\frac{y^2}{B^2}}$$

Now you can differentiate in the usual way.